# Only get the elements from a list that has any kind of quantity in the beginning of the element in python

Tags: python

I have created a list from a string with the split function using comma separator. The list looks like the following:

```
mylist = ['2       boneless skinless chicken breast halves', ' cut into thin strips ', '4   ounces    linguine', ' cooked al dente ', '2   teaspoons    cajun seasoning (your recipe', ' \\u003ca href\\u003d\\"https://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/cajun-seasoning-mix-14190\\"\\u003eCajun Seasoning Mix\\u003c/a\\u003e or store-bought)', '2   tablespoons    butter', '1      thinly sliced green onion', '1/2  cup    heavy whipping cream', '2   tablespoons   chopped sun-dried tomatoes', '1/4  teaspoon    salt', '1/4  teaspoon    dried basil', '1/8  teaspoon    ground black pepper', '1/8  teaspoon    garlic powder', '1/4  cup   grated parmesan cheese']
```

Now I will like to get the `list[0]` element since it has an integer at the front but I don't want the `list[1]` since it has no integer. `List[0]` has an integer like 2 in the beginning. It is also possible that it can be something like 1/2 cup.
So I want to get only the list items that has any kind of quantity value in the beginning. Other items I will discard. How can I filter this elements?
Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was your result?

Comment: I tried doing the following:
Take each item from mylist use split function using spaces. Then use typecasting the first element of my second list. If it succeeds then there is a quantity present else I discard that item of mylist.
The problem is how can i do multiple typecast because it can be both integer and fraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good case for a regular expression:

```
import re

mylist = ['2       boneless skinless chicken breast halves',
          ' cut into thin strips ', '4   ounces    linguine',
          ' cooked al dente ', '2   teaspoons    cajun seasoning (your recipe',
          ' \\u003ca href\\u003d\\"https://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/cajun-seasoning-mix-14190\\"\\u003eCajun Seasoning Mix\\u003c/a\\u003e or store-bought)',
          '2   tablespoons    butter', '1      thinly sliced green onion', '1/2  cup    heavy whipping cream', '2   tablespoons   chopped sun-dried tomatoes', '1/4  teaspoon    salt', '1/4  teaspoon    dried basil', '1/8  teaspoon    ground black pepper', '1/8  teaspoon    garlic powder', '1/4  cup   grated parmesan cheese']

rx = re.compile(r'\d+(?:/\d+)?')

filtered = [item
            for item in mylist
            if rx.match(item)]
print(filtered)
```

---

The expression here is

```
\d+(?:/\d+)?
```

Comment: Hello. I have a question. What happens if the qunatity is like 3-4 cups. Will that also get extracted?

Answer (score 1):

A simple comprehension that should do exactly what you described. 
It check first characters if it is a number, if it is, append the string to the new list.

```
newy = [s for s in y if s[0].isdigit()]
```